# Specific random number generator

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I need to generate numbers in between a specific range and after 1st cycle if number doesn't suit, I need to delete it from the range.

Example:

> I am going to generate random number from range [1-55]. I want number
>   24 but generated through random generator. After first cycle random
>   generator has generate number 4. In next cycle i want to generate
>   random number from same range but number 4 is excluded. So range is -
>   [1,54] / {4}. If in next cycle was number 28 generated the range will
>   change to - [1,54] /{4,28}. Cycles will repeat until the number 24 is
>   not generated.

I need it for my evolutionary algorithm. If i use big ranges it takes so long to generate the needed number through random number generation algorithm. I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: How far have you gotten?

Comment: What is he typical starting range

Comment: There is no typical range it depends on user input. But let the range which I wrote in example be a typical range. I have just generate random number from range [1-54] but have no idea how to continue. How to exlude generated number?

Comment: Search for Fisher–Yates shuffle and Floyd's algorithm to generate random numbers without repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an array containing the full range:

```
int range[55];
std::iota(range, range+55, 1);
```

Start with `n = 55`.

Now, at each step:

- select a random number `i` from `0` to `n-1`
- swap `range[i]` with `range[n-1]`.
- decrement `n`

If the value at the index you selected was 24, then you're done. The values selected prior to 24 are at the right hand side of your array, and the remaining unselected values are at the left.

I'm assuming of course that you need to know those values. If all you need is to generate the value `24` then `int generate24() { return 24;}` should do it. If all you need to know is how many steps it takes to generate 24, then that's uniformly distributed on the range `1` to `55`, so you can probably fake it with a single random number generation.